# Using postfix as an outbound gateway for Mailman

Tags: postfix, mailman

I need some help diagnosing a problem using postfix as my outbound mail server with Mailman.

Up front I want to say, I have this working FINE with my current mailman list server.  I'm in the process of moving my list server to an AWS lightsail instance.

And, yes, I know that I could use postfix as both the inbound & outbound mail server ... which I probably should do, but I'm far more familiar with using sendmail and have it setup & working fine on my current list server.

I've got just about everything setup and working fine.

The problem is, I'm seeing this in my mail log...

Nov 15 15:41:43 lists postfix/smtp[18136]: AA76A61E61: to=, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for localhost loops back to myself)

It *appears* that postfix thinks it's the mail server for lists.atestdomain.net and can't deliver the mail because it doesn't know how to deliver the message.

Here's my current setup:

I have sendmail listening on the public SMTP ports on the server. I have postfix listening on localhost:24. Mailman is configured with the SMTPHOST & SMTPPORT set to localhost & 24.

So mail is received by sendmail, sent to & processed by Mailman, and Mailman sends the mail out by connecting to postfix on localhost:24.

The list mail is being delivered fine ... but bounces are not getting processed correctly.

I have the domain lists.atestdomain.net listed in the transport map indicating that mail for that domain should be sent to localhost:25.

You can see a relatively complete log fragment at https://code.midrange.com/e665e40f93.html

Here's (what I think are) the relevant postfix config file entries ...

main.cf:

```
myhostname = listmail.arealdomain.com
mydomain = $myhostname
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

transport:

```
lists.atestdomain.net smtp:localhost:25
listmail.arealdomain.com smtp:localhost:25
```

master.cf

```
24      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

Any suggestions on what to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW: I bit the bullet and switched to postfix for both inbound & outbound mail.